# Hide stock status on product page depending on other product attribute

Tags: php, product-attribute, stock, html

I have a dropdown product attribute named: `shine_fine` .
i want to hide stock status from product page when any option from `shine_fine` attribute is selected. i don't want to disable `Magento stock status` i just want to hide it.

**update:**

this is my `shine_fine` attribute code in view.phtml:

```
<?php if($_shineFine = $_product->getAttributeText('shine_fine')): ?>
    <img src="/media/atticons/<?php echo $_shineFine ?>.png">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for more of a javascript solution?

Comment: @Egregory could it be done with java script? or i need to make an extension?

Comment: You can probably do it pretty simply with javascript. Since it's client side interaction you are trying to detect you would have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file `app/design/frontend/package/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml` (or) (or copy from app/design/base/default/template)

Add logic around the output.

```
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus() && !$_product->getAttributeText('shine_fine')): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, if your attribute is set, no output will be shown.

(Added another answer after your last edits and additions)

Comment: there is not `template/catalog/product/type/default.phtml` in any of my packages!

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the `/view` - edit my answer

Comment: its working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest template and have jquery.

Add this after your custom attribute.

```
jQuery('#idtoattribute').focus(function(){
    jQuery('#tothestockstatuselement').hide();
}).blur(function(){
    jQuery('#tothestockstatuselement').show();
});
```

Comment: im new in magento and also jQuery.i updated my question. i will thankful if you tell me where to put this code in my view.phtml